# Preventing a absolutely positioned box from leaving its parents container?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a setup similar to code below, where there can be any number of items.

```
<div class="align-center" style="box-shadow: none; margin: 20px 0 0 20px; position: relative">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <label class="photobox box-shadow clear-inner radius" style="display: inline-block; margin: 20px 20px 0 0" for="col_75291999308">
        <img class="radius-left cursor-pointer" height="128" width="128" alt="[thumb]" src="images/collection/thumb/penguins-madagascar-dr-blowhole.jpg" />
        <span class="large bold text-shadow black-text" style="line-height: 128px; padding: 0 5px">‣</span>
    </label>
    <input id="col_75291999308" class="switch single" type="radio" name="description" />
    <div class="box box-shadow" style="border: 5px solid #379; border-radius: 10px; left: 50%; margin: -74px 0 0 -266px; position: absolute; width: 512px; z-index: 999">Information</div>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

If you're curious, I'll provide the CSS for the photo box. All the other classes are kind of self-explanatory (aside from box, which just applies a background and border radius).

```
input.switch { display: none }
input.switch.single + div { display: none }
input.switch.single:checked + div { display: block }

.photobox { background: #DDD; display: block; height: 128px; overflow: hidden }
.photobox:hover { background: #D5D5D5 }
.photobox > img { background: #CCC url('images/smooth/loading.png') repeat; border-right: 1px solid #BCC3C7; float: left; height: 128px; width: 128px }
.photobox > div, .position > span { cursor: pointer; height: 108px; margin-left: 129px; padding: 10px; position: relative }
.photobox > span { margin-left: 0 }
.photobox > div > .floater { color: #EEE; display: block; line-height: 14px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: -123px; text-shadow: -1px 0 #333, 0 1px #333, 1px 0 #333, 0 -1px #333 }
.photobox:hover > div > .floater { opacity: 1.0; transition: opacity .5s linear }
```

This is not the entire code, but basically each division corresponds to a label and input radio box. By default, the division is hidden and the label activates the radio box that corresponds to it, which then unhides the division immediately after it (the radio boxes are always hidden).

The idea is that the absolutely positioned element will center horizontally in the parent container and then stay at the same *y* position that it appears at normally (by not specifying top or bottom). However, the items in the very last row will cause this "popup" box to flow past the bottom of the parent container.

**How can I prevent any and all of these boxes from extending past the bottom of the container?** Basically, if there's enough room, stay in the position it's at. If there's not enough room, it should push the box up to the bottom of the container. Is this possible with **only CSS**?

[image: example]

Keep in mind that this example just happens to use four columns, but the number of columns is completely dependent on the size of the client's screen. Please don't suggest server-side checks to "determine" if the item will be in the last row. Also, just to emphasize, **no JavaScript**.

Comment: "However, the items in the very last row will cause this "popup" box to flow past the bottom of the parent container." - I think you need to post more code. I don't understand how your last row is causing your popup box to change position.

Comment: @mrtsherman: It's not. If you look at the image, you'll see the popup box always shows at the baseline of the item that expands it. The problem is in the last row, this causes it to go outside the parent container.

Comment: I get what you're going for here. Need to see your HTML/CSS to give you a specific answer, because there is no "general" solution.

Comment: @Madmartigan: I added some more detailed code. If you need a live example for some reason, you can view it [here](http://animuson.me/collection).

Comment: @animuson: GL, I'll have to check it out tomorrow, time to crash. At first glance of the live demo, I'd say to leave it alone, it's fine :/ Actually I'd prefer it the way it is because it's consistent, but I don't mean to shoot down your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible with pure CSS. I tried everything I could thing of but the closest solution I could get was using `:nth-last-of-type(-n+6)` to push up the division for the last 6 items in the grid. The only problem with that solution was when a user resized the window (either smaller or larger), there weren't always exactly 6 elements in the last row.

I ended up retheming my site recently which now uses a definitive width, where there will *always* be 6 items in the last row, so the `:nth-last-of-type(-n+6)` selector works for me in this case.

The only thing I could think of is if CSS ever implemented a `:last-line` selector similar to the existing `:first-line` selector, which would allow you to select the last line and then select each division inside that line... maybe? I don't know if that's even possible with that selector.

Aside from using a fixed width for the parent, the idea from the comments is the next best way to go. As long as their is a sufficient amount of content below the parent (maybe a few extra lines), the expansion past the parents' boundaries is not a huge deal and could just be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand what you want but maybe this will help you..

Set an wrapping div with an fixed height, and auto width, and set overflow to hidden?

Comment: This will just hide the rest of the popup box, only displaying the top bit which is not outside of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about absolute positioning is that you now have 4 other commands at your disposal. `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`. `top` will push the element down. `bottom` will push the element up. `left` will push the element to the right, and of course `right` pushes the element to the left. So if I am correctly understanding your question, all you need to do is use the `bottom` command like so:`bottom:200px;`. That should put the child element back inside the parent element. Does this help?

Comment: The problem is this would force *all* the popup boxes to be at the same position relative to the bottom, even those which don't need to be readjusted. The idea is to only push up those boxes which extend past the bottom of the parent container, like in the right side of the example image.

Comment: Well, if you only want to adjust certain ones, using css, there are only two ways I know of. First, if the popups that need adjusting are similar enough, you could give them the same css `class`, and then add `bottom` or `margin, or the like; otherwise, you could set a css `id`, and target each problem popup individually.

Comment: The problem with that is I don't know how many items will appear in each row. It could be anywhere between 3 and 7 depending on the user's browser size.

Comment: Unless you can play around with margin bottom tricks you may need something besides css... If you are online between 9:05 and 12:30 Eastern we can take this to a chat room and you could send me a link to work through myself...